# Why does GetSqlDecimal throw when GetDecimal doesn't?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a database table that has a column of type `money`, allowing nulls. Using a `SqlDataReader` named reader, I can do

```
decimal d = reader.GetDecimal(1);
```

which works, unless of course we're reading a null. If I try using `SqlDecimal` instead—and I thought the whole point of the SqlTypes was to deal with nulls—then I get an invalid cast, **whether or not the value is null**.

```
SqlDecimal s = reader.GetSqlDecimal(1);  // throws an invalid cast exception
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I really have to write a conditional statement to shepherd the value from the database to a `SqlDecimal` variable?

Answer (score 1):

I bet your value fits in a Decimal but not in a SqlDecimal.

> SqlDecimal has different underlying data structures from its corresponding .NET Framework Decimal data type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From the documents:

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a decimal value, or an exception is generated.

My suspicion is that the value in the column is already a decimal, not sqldecimal, because you are using money (which is 18,4, i think), and not the full 38 precision decimal.  Does this happen if you make a straight SqlDecimal with full precision?

Since you are using **money**, a regular decimal should be sufficient.  And in that case, since decimal is lower "precision" in a way, you aren't losing anything.  Life will be easier for all your downstream code too.

Or you can do the conversion like this:

```
SqlDecimal s = new SqlDecimal(reader.GetDecimal(1));
```